# How to link QDjango/other Qt-based CMS and Apache with mod_fastcgi support?

Tags: qt, orm, fastcgi

I'm registered at hosting with Apache and mod_fastcgi support. How can I link `QDjangoFastCgiServer` to Apache? So I need explanation more detailed than this
http://www.treefrogframework.org/documents/cooperation-with-the-reverse-proxy-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the "http-server" example provided QDjango?

https://github.com/jlaine/qdjango/blob/master/examples/http-server/http-server.cpp

Just the example, then run:

./qdjango-http-server runfcgi

This will give you an FCGI application listening on port 8000. You can then tell apache to pass traffic to that application.